# Docker PHP-APACHE container set the ServerName directive globally

Tags: php, apache, docker, dockerfile

I get this warning when i try to run my php:apache container on docker please any idea how to solve this.

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName'
>   directive globally to suppress this message AH00558: apache2: Could
>   not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using
>   172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message [Mon Feb 19 14:18:21.041074 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1]
>   AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/7.0.27 configured -- resuming
>   normal operations [Mon Feb 19 14:18:21.041534 2018] [core:notice] [pid
>   1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Nice but how :P ??

Comment: If you know the exact answer please give it to me and thanks for all the informations :)

Comment: why give negative votes ? :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Voila thanks to aserre for the help:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: You could also expose the port when setting the ServerName:
`RUN echo "ServerName localhost:80" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
Meaning you may not have to explicitly call `EXPOSE`.

Comment: Also don't forget to install the `database driver` in case you're to connect to one e.g MySQL

Answer (score 29):

Do it [like you would do on a regular system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155150/where-in-apache-2-do-you-set-the-servername-directive-globally):

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

You can change the server name to suit your configuration.

Comment: I tried this but i got exiting from the container every time when i want to run it  i use also flag lik -d -i -t but i don't understund why the container exit.

Comment: Does it exit with an error ? What is the status when you do docker ps -a ? If you don't run a command on your container, it will exit, that's the expected behaviour. Have you defined an entrypoint ?

Comment: Docker ps -a: ` root@r00t:~/Documents/DOCKER/containers/dockerfiles/basic-03# docker run -t -d -p 80:4000 --name my-app-v4 helloworldnavphpv-7
b24a3c035a4d321189f137fd08163a6f262a3a4df8b8900d0fa67ff4f2ff068e
root@r00t:~/Documents/DOCKER/containers/dockerfiles/basic-03# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
b24a3c035a4d        helloworldnavphpv-7   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   6 seconds ago       Exited (0) 4 seconds ago                           my-app-v4
 `

Comment: It seems the container exited without error, so there was no command executed. Try adding an entrypoint to launch apache

Comment: Please Aserre can you explain to me how to do this i'm new  to DOCKER

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Centos as base, it should look like this:

```
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
CMD apachectl -DFOREGROUND
```

regards