# Docker compose, apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know a very similar answer has already been dealt with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868357/docker-php-apache-container-set-the-servername-directive-globally/48868602) BUT in my case I am using an already made docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop/) and I don't think I can modify the **Dockerfile**

I think I need to execute this command `echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but I don't know *how*, idealy I would like to gather all the configurations in the **docker-compose.yml** file, here it is:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image: prestashop/prestashop:1.7
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      DB_SERVER: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass123
      MYSQL_DB: prestashop

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop
```

When I run  `docker-compose up` I get this "error"

> phpmyadmin_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

> app_1         | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Any idea ?

Thank you

Aymeric

Comment: Maybe the documented `PS_DOMAIN` environment variable may solve your issue?

Comment: Sorry, the error actually involved phpmyadmin container instead of Prestashop one, but thanks for the tip !

Comment: Sorry didn't read fully the question, and as you start it by talking about changing the prestashop image... The servername message is not an "error", it's just a warning saying that it's defaulting to the container IP, it should not have any impact. Do you have any issue using the phpmyadmin container? Anyway maybe `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI` en var could help.

Comment: Sorry again, I also have this warning on the prestashop image, but it appeared after on the logs... I just updated my post

Comment: You just want to get rid of the message or you encounter a real issue using your prestashop containerized stack? In the second case: what is your real issue? Does opening localhost:8080 gets you to your prestashop site? Does opening localhost:8081 gets you to phpmyadmin?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the message, I don't have any problem opening any container (only that it's quite slow, but It's another problem)

Comment: Is the message still there when using the pointed en vars ?

Comment: Just point out that you can always modify image, even if you don't have the build scripts for it. All you need to do is to use this image as a starting point in your build and add the modifications you need.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski  please, could you indicate how to do this ? (or send me a link)

Comment: @zigarn yes still here

Comment: To extend the image to change the Servername, look at the dockerfile documentation and specially the `FROM` and `RUN` instructions. But really not sure it worth it to build images to get rid of an innocent warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the container by creating the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM prestashop/prestashop:1.7

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and modify the docker-compose.yml

```
...
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: /var/www/html
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I just did this but I still have the warning, and no "ServerName localhost" written at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: It's working fine for me. To verify, after you have started the composition, docker will build new image. You can see this with `docker image ls`. The name will most probably be `test_app:latest`. To check that the command was execute use `docker image history <<image name>>`. Start instance of the image `docker run --entrypoint bash -ti --rm <<image name>>` and than inspect the file. In my case, I can see the line added in the file

Comment: Working fine for me too!

Comment: According to https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/issues/293 a fully qualified domain name is required for the hostname in docker-compose.yaml.